# Comparing fields in $where clause in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, where-clause

Trying to find out if desc and atr.value for atr.key="DSP" are equal in following mongo table data:

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("12345"),
"desc": "Foo Bar",
"type": "Normal",
"atr": 
[
{
"key":"DSP",
"value":"Goo Bar"
},
{
"key":"UDSP",
"value":"Foo Bar"
}
],
"prod": "yes"
}
```

Running following query but not getting appropriate results:

```
db.collection.find({$and: [{"atr.key" : { $eq:"DSP"}},{$where: "this.atr.value=this.desc"}]})
```

Getting 0 results instead of 1.

Comment: The answer I proposed below were not edits, it's the solution itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your brackets are misplaced.

The json object contains an array named "attr" which should be surrounded by [] and not by {}.

```
"atr": [
   {
      "key":"DSP",
      "value":"Goo Bar"
   },
   {
      "key":"UDSP",
      "value":"Foo Bar"
   }
],
```

And so does the query, the { in the "$eq" statement is misplaced. Here is the query:

```
db.data.find(
{
    $and: [
        {"atr.key" : {$eq:"DSP"}}, 
        {$where: "this.atr.value=this.desc"}
    ]
})
```

The changed statement is {$eq:"DSP"}.

Comment: Actually this is the answer for your problem, not edit suggestions.